# V-textarea value still leaves a lot of space on the left and top margins

Tags: javascript, vuetify.js, textarea, literals

I Have problems with v-textarea when i call may v-model on v-textarea like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lcUCF.png)

text does not fit either the left or top margin and always leaves a lot of space on the left and top. How do I solve this problem?
ini adalah code v-textarea:

```
<v-textarea
 name="input-7-1"
 filled
 auto-grow
 height="500"
 v-model="content"
></v-textarea>
```

this is one of the codes referring to `content` variables:

```
if(this.content == ``){
  query= `${prefix}
  Select ${this.arrmeasureGabung}
  where{
    ?obs rdf:type qb:Observation ;
    ${this.arrquerymeasuregabung}.
  }`
  this.content = query;
}
```

Comment: Did you try `class='pa-0'`?

Comment: that's not works

Comment: @timotydev-03 so it's probably because spaces in the string, try `\n` instead of using enter and tab. for example `query = \`${prefix}\nSelect.....\``

Answer (score 0):

You can set

```
$text-field-enclosed-details-padding: 0;
```

to remove the left padding